# For a positive integer $n$, prove that $\sum_{d|n}{(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)}=0,\textit{if n is even and -n if n is odd.}$

Tags: number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, prove that $$\sum_{d|n}{(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)}=
\begin{cases}0&\text{if $n$ is even }\\ -n & \text{if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}$$

I totally have no idea how to solve this. I try to plug in some examples to see some connections, but i fail. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: I don't get it: do you want to prove the sum is zero for even n and -n for odd n?

Comment: @DonAntonio: yes

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The functions $(-1)^n$ and $\varphi(n)$ are *multiplicative.*

It follows by general theory that the function $f(n)$, where 
$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n} (-1)^{n/d}\varphi(d)$$
is multiplicative.

Thus you only need to deal with prime powers.  We do a little of the work for $n=p^k$, where $p$ is an odd prime. Then all the $(-1)^{n/d}$ are $-1$. Forgetting about the $-1$ for a while, we want 
$$\varphi(1)+\varphi(p)+\cdots+\varphi(p^k).$$
This is 
$$1+(p-1)+(p-1)p+\cdots+(p-1)p^{k-1}.$$
The formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression will give you a nice simplified answer.

**Remark:** You may already know a formula for $\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)$, it is typically done quite early. Then you can bypass the above computations, and obtain the result very quickly.

Comment: The function $(-1)^n$ is *not* multiplicative: $(-1)^{mn} \not= (-1)^m(-1)^n$ unless $m$ and $n$ are both even (in which case both sides are $1$).

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd, each $\frac{n}{d}$ is odd, so each $(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}=-1$ and $$\sum_{d>0,\;d|n}(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)=\sum_{d>0,\;d|n}-\phi(d)=-\sum_{d>0,\;d|n}\phi(d)=-n.$$If $n=2^m$ (with $m\geq1$) then each $\frac{n}{d}$ is even except when $d=2^m$, so  $(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}=1$ when $0<d<n$ and $$\sum_{d>0,\;d|n}(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)=\sum_{n>d>0,\;d|n}[(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)]-\phi(n)=\sum_{n>d>0,\;d|n}\phi(d)-\phi(n)=(n-\phi(n))-\phi(n)=n-2\phi(n).$$But $n-2\phi(n)=2^m-2\phi(2^m)=2^m-2\cdot2^{m-1}=2^m-2^m=0.$ Finally, I showed that for even $n=2^mk$ (with $k>1$ odd), the function

$$f_n(d)=  
  \begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $d\not |\;\,n$} \\
                                   (-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d) & \text{if $d\,\;|\,\;n$} \\
\end{cases}$$
is multiplicative. Hence so is $F(n)=\sum_{d>0,\;d|n}(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)$. Then $$\sum_{d>0,\;d|n}(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)=F(2^mk)=F(2^m)F(k)=[\sum_{d>0,\;d|2^m}(-1)^{\frac{2^m}{d}}\phi(d)]\cdot F(k)=0\cdot F(k)=0,$$since we already showed the sum is 0 for powers of 2. QED.